# WFS FlatGeobuf output format produces parsing error

Tags: geoserver, format

I use GeoServer to output WFS FlatGeobuf format, and then add it to a new datastore, but GeoServer doesn't seem to be able to parse the geometry. I can't preview it as well. When I use WFS to GetFeature as JSON, the response is like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "facilities_fgb.0",
            "geometry": null,
            "properties": {
                "geom": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates":
```

Comment: Does ogrinfo find features and geometries from that fgb file?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: why are you trying to round trip the file? how did you set up the original layer? Does it show up in the preview? Can you display the WFS in QGIS?

Comment: Because I'm verifying publishing flatgeobuf data with Geoserver, but I don't currently have data in that format. So my idea is to use Geoserver to export flatgeobuf data. The original layer works properly. The QGIS can also identify the flatgeobuf file. 
By the way, flatgeobuf files exported with QGIS cannot be added to the data source on the Geoserver, the error information is as follows:
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: This is not a flatgeobuf!